# working directory for python does not return result

Tags: python-2.7, directory

I am trying to run this code

```
import os

def faisal():
    os.getcwd()
    file_name=os.getcwd()
    print(file_name)
```

I am expecting to know the current directory of python, however shell returns the following

```
=================== RESTART: C:/Python27/Rename Project.py ===================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are defining your function, however you aren't calling it. Add this to your code:

```
faisal()
```